# Created Python Script to merge PDF files works fine in Pycharm but not as a solo EXE I made via pyinstaller

Tags: python, pdf, exe, pyinstaller

So this is my code below.AS stated in the title it works as intended in PyCharm but not outside of it. Would it be because I used PyPDF2 library? Thank you any help would be much appreciated.

```
import os

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

def main():

    print("PDF Merger Initialized")

    pdfs = [pdf_file for pdf_file in os.listdir() if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf")] #sets pdfs as a list containing all files with the .pdf extenstion

    merger = PdfFileMerger()

    for pdf in pdfs:
        merger.append(pdf)

    merger.write("merged_bills.pdf")
    merger.close()


    print("PDF Merger Completed")


main()
```

Comment: if you run your exe from the commandline your will probably see some traceback about why it isnt working ... at a guess its because `os.listdir` takes an argument and only returns the filename not the path to the file

Comment: Okay, I ran in in command and it goes through fine just nothing happens. I take a closer look at the path file you mentioned.

Comment: I tested your script on my computer and the exe works just fine. Are your pdf in the same folder as the exe ?

Comment: @EricMathieu hmmm..yes I have them in same folder. Did you use Pyinstaller aswell? Maybe I’ll have to try on a different pc.

Comment: @GiorgioSau: yes i am using pyinstaller. If you run your exe in a console what is the output ?

Comment: @EricMathieu nothing, its runs with no errors but the merged pdf is not created.

Comment: @GiorgioSau. It's wierd since even if there is no file I get the two lines printed and a empty merged pdf is created.  Can you build your exe with --debug=all and provide the output of the execution ?

Comment: @EricMathieu This is what I got                                                                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merger_code.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

Comment: @GiorgioSau I frequently have this issue: you intall the module within PyCharm environment but when you build the exe it is using the global environment which do not have the new module. Just open a console and install PyPDF2 then build the exe from the same console.

Comment: @EricMathieu will try! Thanks for all the help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try instead

```
import glob

pdfs = [pdf_file for pdf_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"*.pdf")]
```

glob will return the full path to the file in this way

alternatively try

```
pdfs = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(),pdf_file) for pdf_file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf")]
```